# Returning a distinct list of mac addresses for devices which meet the two conditions below

Tags: sql, union

Conditions:

the device has a user named “Hack3r”
the device has been the host in over 100 connections that started in 2021

Relational Schema:

```
Device [mac, state, brand, model, serialNumber] 
DeviceUser [mac, user]
Connects [host, client, timestamp, duration]
```

I believe we are looking at a UNION function here but I am just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your SQL type, but you should be adapt the syntax for this answer.  This answer assumes that host from Connects is a mac address.  If not, let me know, and I'll delete this.

```
select du.mac from deviceuser du
join connects c on du.mac=c.host
where du.user='Hack3r' and year(c.timestamp)=2021
group by du.mac
having count(*) > 100;
```

Comment: Hi eshi, thank you for the response!  What do you mean by SQL type?  Excuse me, I am quite new to this.  I think we are required to use a UNION condition here...

Comment: This query should return a table with a single column containing mac addresses of all devices that meet either of the two conditions described above, correct?